# How to format code blocks

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, formatting

How can I post a block of Emacs Lisp code?

How can I post some buffer content including special characters and not have them interpreted as markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include some text in a monospaced font with no formatting, put ```` ``` ```` on a line on its own, then the text, then a ```` ``` ```` line again. You may be familiar with this syntax from Github and other Markdown engines. [This syntax is now available on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#322000). Thanks balpha! You can use `~~~` instead of ```` ``` ```` if you prefer.

---

Here's an example:

```
This paragraph is <pre>formatted.
It uses a `code fence'.
```

---

The part of this post between the two horizontal lines above uses the following source syntax:

````
Here's an example:
```
This paragraph is <pre>formatted.
It uses a `code fence'.
```
````

You can get the same effect by indenting the preformatted block with four spaces.

To typeset Emacs Lisp code, start with **```` ```lang-el ````** or `~~~lang-el` instead of a plain ```` ``` ```` or `~~~`. This turns on syntax-based coloring.

```el
(if syntax-indicator (setq coloring t))
```

can be entered with

````
```lang-el
(if syntax-indicator (setq coloring t))
```
````

To get syntax coloring with four-space-indent code blocks, put `<!-- language: lang-el -->` in a paragraph of its own immediately before the code block. To get syntax coloring on all the code blocks in an answer, put `<!-- language-all: lang-el -->` before the first code block.

If you include a code snippet in some other programming language, you can get syntax coloring with the [appropriate `lang-xxx` indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). (Note that on Emacs.SE, because most of the code is Elisp regardless of the tags on a question, the code highlighting is not based on tags.)

Comment: Since most of the code here is Elisp, is it possible to make that the default. i.e., code blocks get elisp syntax highlighting without requiring the `lang-el` flag?

Comment: @Tyler Possible, yes, but [when it came up, Stack Exchange rejected it](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/244) because [it would highlight things that shouldn't be about 1/3 of the time (based on analysing the first few hundred posts on the site)](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11). I [requested a heuristic that has a very high success rate](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/245) but Stack Exchange hasn't implemented it (and to be fair, even though it's simple, it would probably be a pain for them to maintain such per-site heuristics).